# Issue in reading HLS segment files to OpenCV VideoCapture: error reading header

Tags: python, opencv, http-live-streaming

I'm getting the error below when reading HLS(HTTP Live Streaming) segment files to OpenCV, using `cv2.VideoCapture()`

```
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f941f2ca200] could not find corresponding trex
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f941f2ca200] error reading header
```

The segment files are mp4 and HLS server is Amazon Kinesis Video Stream. The error message says that I'm missing header part of mp4 and it looks somehow reasonable because HLS provides a sequence of files.

My question here is, reading HLS segments to OpenCV is totally wrong approach? or we have some workaround?

```py
    import boto3
    import cv2
    import requests
    import re

    kinesis_client = boto3.client('kinesisvideo',
                                  region_name='ap-northeast-1'
                                  )

    endpoint = kinesis_client.get_data_endpoint(
        StreamARN='MY_ARN',
        APIName='GET_HLS_STREAMING_SESSION_URL'
    )

    data_endpoint = endpoint['DataEndpoint']
    url_prefix = data_endpoint + "/hls/v1/"

    video_client = boto3.client('kinesis-video-archived-media',
                                endpoint_url=data_endpoint
                                )

    # Retrieve HLS manifest URL from Kinesis Video Stream
    session_url = video_client.get_hls_streaming_session_url(
        StreamARN='MY_ARN',
        HLSFragmentSelector={'FragmentSelectorType': 'PRODUCER_TIMESTAMP'}
    )

    session_url = session_url['HLSStreamingSessionURL']

    # Fetch segment(mp4) file urls
    master_playlist = requests.get(session_url)
    media_playlist_url = url_prefix + master_playlist.text.split("\n")[-2]
    media_playlist = requests.get(media_playlist_url)
    media_playlist = media_playlist.text
    pattern = r"getMP4Media"
    segments  = filter(lambda x: re.match(pattern,x), media_playlist.split("\n"))

    for segment in segments:
      segment_url = url_prefix + segment

      # Debug segment url
      # This emits something like: https://b-87178fb5.kinesisvideo.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/hls/v1/getMP4MediaFragment.mp4?FragmentNumber=91343852333186478711651164912799448912305946338&SessionToken=CiAFReSdi9NKKz8vDum-Bs_8MFJ-5jIk06WmiyKDQQazihIQLdLPLuvr6scwc4HhAo6uDRoZWbgLHyJK01pTzFujc-cSkfl0oo4pIFD2sSIghdfInJL4XqMc_brBoLCikS73I3Nxxxxxxxxxxx
      print(segment_url)


      # Read mp4 file from Kinesis Video Sterams
      cap = cv2.VideoCapture(segment_url)

      while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)

      cap.release()
```

Comment: The error message `[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f941f2ca200] could not find corresponding trex` suggests that an expected `trex` box was not found in the MP4 file. The `trex` (or Track Extends Box) is contained in the initialization segments of the stream.